# the trait `From<Errors>` is not implemented for `anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError`

Tags: rust, blockchain, smartcontracts, solana

I am trying to write errors enum in a solana smart contract:

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

#[error]
pub enum Errors {
    #[msg("User cannot be created, missing data")]
    CannotCreateUser,

    #[msg("Cannot have more than 5 likes")]
    ReachedMaxLikes,

}
```

I used it like this

```
if image.likes == NUMBER_OF_ALLOWED_LIKES_SPACE  {
            return Err(Errors::ReachedMaxLikes.into());
        }
```

I get this error

```
return Err(Errors::ReachedMaxLikes.into());
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Errors>` is not implemented for `anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError`
   |
```

Instead of `[error]`, I used `[ProgramError]` and `#[derive(ProgramError)]` but error message still exists

Answer (score 1):

Try these on your code:

- Use `#[error_code]` on the enum
- Throw the error like this: `return err!(Errors::ReachedMaxLikes);`
- Double-check that your program method signature is returning `anchor_lang::Result`, not the `std` one

Answer (score 0):

As per the example in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/macro.error.html):

```rust
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

#[error_code]
pub enum Errors {
    #[msg("User cannot be created, missing data")]
    CannotCreateUser,

    #[msg("Cannot have more than 5 likes")]
    ReachedMaxLikes,

}
```

And then:

```rust
if image.likes == NUMBER_OF_ALLOWED_LIKES_SPACE  {
   return Err(error!(Errors::ReachedMaxLikes));
}
```

Comment: I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In the imports section add this `use anchor_lang::Result;` and then in the function return type (Where you return `Err(error!(Errors::ReachedMaxLikes));`) put `Result<()>` .

The function signature should look like this

```
pub fn sign_up(ctx: Context<SignUp> , name: String , user_name: String , phone: String , email: String) -> Result<()> {}
```